# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined while rendering a list of user comments

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios, redux-thunk

I am trying to fetch posts from a fake api (json placeholder) , but I am getting a TypeError which says Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Here is the class component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import fetchPosts from '../actions/postListAction'

 class PostList extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchPosts();
}

  renderList() {
      return this.props.posts.map(post => {
          return (
          <div className="row" key={post.id}>
              <i class="fas fa-user align-left"></i>
              <div className="content">
                  <div className="description">
                      <p>{post.title}</p>
                      <p>{post.body}</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          );
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Posts</h3>
        <div className="post-list">
        {this.renderList()}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { post: state.posts }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPosts })(PostList)
```

Here is the action creator

```
import jsonPlaceholder from '../apis/jsonPlaceholder'

const fetchPosts = () => async dispatch => {
        const response = await jsonPlaceholder.get('/posts');
    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_POSTS', payload: response })
}

export default fetchPosts
```

Here is the reducer

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_POSTS'
        return action.payload;
        default: 
        return state;
    }
}
```

api from jsonplaceholder using axios

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create ({
    baseURL: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/'
})
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You have a typo. You're matching `state.posts` to `props.post` in your `mapStateToProps`. But you try to access `this.props.posts` for your `.map`.

Comment: @TobiasTengler have the answer. Be aware you can use defaultProps to ensure that some props will be not undefined.

Comment: I am little confused, could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo.

in mapStateToProps your matching (POST) to state.posts
but in your map method you’re sayin this.props.(POSTS)
these should be the same. ether post or posts
you have to check your rootReducer and pass the right key too your component